# Something moves sidebar menu after putting table on a website

Tags: html, css, menu, html-table

This menu on the left should be exactly next to that table at right, it's okay on other pages. No idea how to fix it.

[image]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/c5a0e58cf5098fa3ed09a307e8992e9d.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

We need code, the image isn't sufficient

```
<div class="tooted" style="float:left;">
</div>
<div class="menu" style="float:right;">
</div>
<div style="clear:both;">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.tooted{width:50%;}
.menu{width:50%;}
```